# gmplib prevents to debug by using breakpoints

Tags: c++, netbeans, breakpoints, gmp

I have written a C++ program using Netbeans on Linux. It worked fine and could be debugged well. Then I included the gmblib for some arithmetic calculations. The old program now uses the library where needed. If I start the program using the 'Run Project'-command, it seems to run well as before. But I want to check it in details. So I need to create breakpoints and a start of the program using the 'Debug Project'-command. But if I use this command, I get warnings in a 'Debugger Error'-dialog like the following:
`Warning:\nCannot insert breakpoint 1.\nCannot access memory at address 0x5555555a0587\n`
The error message seems to pop up when it comes to the first breakpoint. The program hangs up at each breakpoint and cannot be continued. But it don't stop the execution automatically. Also the error pop ups at a breakpoint in the first line of the main-method, where a memory problem can be excluded in my opinion. Can anyone tell me, how I can solve this problem?

Comment: How did you install GMP?

Comment: I compiled it and included the libraries in linker settings of the project. First the *.a-libraries (gmp and gmpxx), now the *.so-ones. Occasionally I also installed it by using 'make install' and sudo.